# Detect a page submit in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am currently working with reading data from a USB card reader and it sends a page submit command along with the card track data.

Is there a way for me to detect a page submit command and can I programmatically disable the submit command?

Answer (score 2):

Handle the form's `submit` event and return `false` if you want it to be canceled.

For example:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    //Do something
    return !hadErrors;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML it's super-easy:

`<form onsubmit="return false">`

You also do it via code in JQuery like so:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```